# How would a date in HTML file using a .bat script

Tags: html, batch-file, scripting

I have a .html file `titlepage.html` that contains the following line:

`<span class="titlepage modified">Modified: Feb 13, 2020 </span>`

The problem is, that sometimes I forget to change the "Modified: " date

I run a .bat file which moves this `titlepage.html` to the proper location, so I figured it would make sense to add a subroutine in the .bat file to update the date before moving it.

my current .bat file looks like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set infile=titlepage.html
set outfile=result.html
Set find=Modified:
set replace="<span class="titlepage modified">Modified: %DATE% </span>"

del result.html

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=" %%n in (!infile!) do (
set LINE=%%n
set TMPR=!LINE:%find%=%replace%!
echo !TMPR!>>%outfile%
)
```

And the line in question of my looks like: 
`<span class="titlepage modified">"<span class="titlepage modified">Modified: 04/10/20 </span>" Feb 13, 2020 </span>`

So it successfully inputs the information I want, but I need it to replace the entire line in question not just the part I used for the lookup.

*Note the dates will be arbitrary so I can't perform a lookup on the entire line.

So I want to:
 1. Lookup for a line containing a string 
 2. Replace that entire line with my new input.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the relevant output of your script look like?  Does it give you errors? Working with any XML/HTML in a batch script is tricky because of all those special characters.  I am pretty sure you don't need the outer quotes in `set replace = "..."` line, but you do need to escape the `<>` characters. `^<^>`.

Comment: I agree with the above, this task should be revised to use [tag:powershell] instead of a [tag:batch-file].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "target=./titlepage.html"
set "destination=./titlepage.html"
set "find=(?mi)^.*Modified:.*$"
set "replace=<span class=\"titlepage modified\">Modified: %DATE% </span>"

powershell -noprofile -command^
 $content=get-content -path '!target!';^
 $result=$content -replace '!find!', '!replace!';^
 set-content -path '!destination!' -value $result
```

`powershell` reads the the target `./titlepage.html`, does the replacement and writes to the destination `./titlepage.html`.

The regular expression pattern searches for `Modified:` in a line. The `find` variable contains the pattern and uses options `(?mi)`. The `m` is multiline mode and the `i` is case insensitive. If you want case insensitive, remove the `i`.

Regular expression pattern:

- `(?mi)` Regular expression options. `m` is multiline and `i` is case insensitive.
- `^` By default, the match must start at the beginning of the string; in multiline mode, it must start at the beginning of the line.
- `.` Wildcard: Matches any single character except \n.
- `*` Matches the previous element zero or more times.
- `$` By default, the match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the string; in multiline mode, it must occur before the end of the line or before \n at the end of the line.

Replacement string:

- `\"` Escape nested double quote for command line parsing to `powershell`.

View the [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) for more information.

The `^` at the end of lines, of the `powershell` command, are line continuations.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but there doesn't seem to be a result of running the script. I tried to play around with different date formats and different paths to the titlepage.html. But there is seems to be no change to the titlepage.html as well as it is not throwing any sort of errors or warnings at runtime.

Comment: I have updated the code to resemble the OP code as the previous pattern I posted is in doubt, based on your arbitrary needs. So long as the file is read, processed and written, no errors should display. If the pattern does not match, then the file content will not change.